# Receiving message in a transaction

Tags: c#, msmq, msmq-transaction

I am writing a basic MSMQ producer and consumer and I'm getting tripped up when trying to receive a message as part of a transaction.

The queue is on a Windows Server 2003 machine and it is definitely set to transactional. My producer is able to put messages onto the queue as part of a transaction with no problems. I can read the messages off the queue without problems as well, as long as I don't do it in a transaction. What am I doing wrong?

This is the block of code with which I'm trying to consume the queue:

```
using (MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(myQueueName))
{                   
    try
    {
        using (MessageQueueTransaction msgTx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
        {
            msgTx.Begin();

            msg = msgQ.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000), msgTx);
            Console.WriteLine("Message " + msg.LookupId.ToString() + " received");
            msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new string[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
            if (ParseMessage(msg.Body.ToString()))
            {
                msgTx.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("Message " + msg.LookupId.ToString() + " delivered");
            }
            else
            {
                msgTx.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine("Message " + msg.LookupId.ToString() + " not delivered");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MessageQueueException exc)
    {
        if (exc.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)
            Console.WriteLine("No more messages available");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown error encountered while receiving");
    }
}
```

So if I remove the `using (MessageQueueTransaction ...)` encapsulation, everything works fine, except of course that I can't `commit` or `abort` the transaction depending on the boolean outcome of `ParseMessage(...)`

When I add the transactional bits though, I get a `MessageQueueException` as soon as I hit the `msgQ.Receive(...)` line. The exception message and base is null and the `MessageQueueErrorCode` is `0xc00e008b` which, according to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) translates to:

> MQ_ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED_BY_REMOTE_COMPUTER (0xC00E008B)
>
> Returned when an attempt is made to receive or peek at a message using
>   a lookup identifier from a remote queue residing on a computer running
>   MSMQ 1.0 or MSMQ 2.0.

Now, to the best of my knowledge, I'm not trying to receive or peek based on a lookup identifier plus, the MSMQ is running on Windows Server 2003 which means it should be MSMQ 3.0 anyway.

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing a Remote Transactional Receive. This was introduced in MSMQ 4.0. Upgrade the server to a supported operating system.

> [How do I get transactional remote receives with MSMQ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/12/11/how-do-i-get-transactional-remote-receives.aspx)